# Determining the Return Type of a Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, invoke, return-type, decltype

Given that I have a return type which is determined by a template argument, like so:

```
template <typename T>
conditional_t<is_same_v<T, int>, int, char> foo(const T&);
```

I thought that I could use `decltype(foo<float>)` to get this type but it doesn't seem to be working.

I don't have [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) so I cannot use `invoke_result_t`.

Comment: How does it not seem to work?

Comment: Pretty sure that you want `is_same_v<T, int>` (or `is_same<T, int>::value`) instead of `is_same<T, int>`. The first `template` parameter of `std::conditional_t` expects a value, not a type.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()))` if you want a return type, not the function type?

Comment: Shouldn't you use something as `decltype(foo(0.0f))` to get a return type? See https://wandbox.org/permlink/MwKsxcY8aGCWXPl1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that I could use `decltype(foo<float>)` to get this type but it doesn't seem to be working.

The expression `foo<float>` refers to the function, so the `decltype` will be related with the type of the template function (i.e., `char (const float&)`).

---

What you are looking for is:

```
decltype(foo(std::declval<float>()))
```

That is, the expression returned by function `foo` when a `float` is given as input.

*Of course, you can substitute `float` with any type in order to obtain the different results of the template function.*

---

Example Code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Your template function
template <typename T>
std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, int, char> foo(const T&);

void test() {
  decltype(foo(std::declval<float>())) x;  // x is char in this case

  // We can test the type of x at compile time

  static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int>, "error");  // x is not an int
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), char>, "error");  // x is a char
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`decltype(foo<float>)` will give you a function type, something like `char (float const&)`. To get the return type you can use

```
using R = decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()));   // T = float
```